# Android - update folder display after capture image

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-camera

I'm new to android. Now, i'm doing image capturing function using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
```

The problem is after I capture my photo, the new captured photo does not display on the image display page.

Does anyone here know where there is code that can help me refresh my android or any step that I need to do so that my image display page can be updated once I capture a new photo?

Any help would be very appreciated and many thanks to you first.

Updated answer:
I use this, may be this can help others:

```
                mScanner = new MediaScannerConnection(
                Camera.this,
                new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                        mScanner.scanFile(outputFileUri.getPath(), null /* mimeType */);
                    }

                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        //we can use the uri, to get the newly added image, but it will return path to full sized image
                        //e.g. content://media/external/images/media/7
                        //we can also update this path by replacing media by thumbnail to get the thumbnail
                        //because thumbnail path would be like content://media/external/images/thumbnail/7
                        //But the thumbnail is created after some delay by Android OS
                        //So you may not get the thumbnail. This is why I started new UI thread
                        //and it'll only run after the current thread completed.
                        if (path.equals(outputFileUri.getPath())) {
                            mScanner.disconnect();
                            //we need to create new UI thread because, we can't update our mail thread from here
                            //Both the thread will run one by one, see documentation of android  
                            Camera.this
                            .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
        mScanner.connect();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sally, did you mean that after you take a photo you don't see it in the gallery or file-manager when you look at the directory you know the file to be in?

If so, you need to run the media-scanner like this:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri));
```

... where uri is the uri of the photo, since you know it already, although you can use the uri of the directory instead if that's easier (though it is slower - potentially very slow if the directory contains many files or nested directories).

Comment: folder not appearing in gallery

Answer (score 1):

you should take photo using below code::

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),(cal.getTimeInMillis()+".jpg"));
if(!file.exists()){
try {
file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedImageUri);
startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);
```

and on activity result you can use these code:::

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
switch (requestCode) {
case CAMERA_RESULT:
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
try {
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. actually i can take photo and save it in my sdcard. The problem is, I have a page that will display the images of that directory, after I take a new photo, but the page are not displaying the new captured photo. Hope that I make my question clear, sorry if my explanation not clear. :)

Comment: What is this: _activity.getContentResolver() 
It gives an error on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh your activity with :

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Hi noli, thanks for your reply. But may I know where should i place this code? is inside the oncreate part or other part? because when i place it in my code, the code will have infinity loop. Any idea would be very appreciate. thanks